# How to install models/download packages on Google Colab?

Tags: nltk, spacy, google-colaboratory

I am using text analytics library "Spacy". I've installed spacy on Google Colab notebook without any issue. But for using it I need to download "en" model.

Generally, that command should look like this:

```
python -m spacy download en
```

I tried few ways but I am not able to get it to install on the notebook. Looking for help.

Cheers

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have a Python interpreter but not a teriminal, you could try:

```
import spacy.cli
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_sm")
```

More manual alternatives can be found here: https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-pip

Fundamentally what needs to happen is the model file needs to be downloaded, unzipped, and placed into the appropriate site-packages directory. You should be able to find a convenient way to do that, e.g. by pip installing the model package directly. But if you get really stuck, you can get the path by looking at the `__file__` variable of any module you have installed, e.g. `print(spacy.__file__`) . That should tell you where on your file-system the site-packages directory is.

Answer (score 6):

```
!python -m spacy download fr_core_news_sm
```

Worked for me for the French model

Answer (score 5):

or you can use:

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

Comment: did not work for me with en_core_web_md, ended up using the accepted answer.