# Unable to load the spacy model 'en_core_web_lg' on Google colab

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, spacy

I am using spacy in google colab to build an NER model for which I have downloaded the spaCy 'en_core_web_lg' model using

```
import spacy.cli
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_lg")
```

and I get a message saying

```
✔ Download and installation successful
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
```

However then when i try to load the model

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
```

the following error is printed:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: As of June 2022, executing ```import spacy.cli; spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_lg"); nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')``` on colab.to doesn't error anymore. Looks to me that the problem vanished!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Running

```
import spacy.cli
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_lg")
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
```

shouldn't yield any errors anymore with recent spaCy versions.

If running the code still gives errors, you should be all set with running in one cell (takes a while, but gives you visual feedback about progress, differently from `spacy.cli`)

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

Then, *** **restart the colab runtime** *** via

- the colab menu `Runtime > Restart runtime`, or
- use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+M .`

After that, executing

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
```

should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 21):

In Google Colab Notebooks, you should [import the model as a package](https://spacy.io/usage/models#usage-import).

However you download and install the model:

```
!pip install <model_s3_url> # tar.gz file e.g. from release notes like https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases//tag/en_core_web_lg-2.3.1
!pip install en_core_web_lg
import spacy
```

you don't have permission in Colab to load the model with normal spacy usage:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg") # not via packages
nlp = spacy.load("/path/to/en_core_web_lg") #not via paths
nlp = spacy.load("en") # nor via shortcut links
spacy.load()
```

Instead, import the ***model*** and load it directly:

```
import en_core_web_lg
nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
```

Then use as directed:

```
doc = nlp("This is a sentence. Soon, it will be knowledge.")
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems the best answer is on this thread: [How to install models/download packages on Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259404/how-to-install-models-download-packages-on-google-colab?rq=1)

```
import spacy.cli
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_lg")
import en_core_web_lg
nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue on google colab with:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```

I suspect it may have something to do with the size of the model.  It worked for me using the small spacy model.

```
spacy download en_core_web_sm
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```